# Is there any advantage of building bytecode than regular actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bytecode

Im very curious , is there any advantage of building SWF using bytecode than regular actionscript ?

As i read there are some ways to speed up code a little , but are there some things that as3code cannot do ?

EDIT:
Please , do not focus on coding style , problems , type checks and syntax , let say ill have external SWF with 1 class written in bytecode and now i like to know what benefits i can get from lower level coding.

Comment: Whatever the advantages, I imagine the disadvantages *greatly* outweigh them.

Comment: @MartyWallace is right when it comes to "regular" programming: You will have no type checks, no syntax checks, not a single helpful compiler feature - as soon as your program grows to more than a few lines of code, you'll have the pain of your lifetime.  It can be quite interesting to find out about how the AVM works, though - and thus perhaps to find ways to optimize your programs after compilation.

Comment: Yeah , i know its hard to do and should not write like that , but only thing i like to know is this allow me to do things i cannot do with pure as3?

Comment: @turbosqel no, this won't allow you to do things you can't do in pure AS3. Even Alchemy is based entirely on and limited by the current sandbox and capabilities of the flash player. There is literally not a single advantage to writing in pure ABC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flash compiler doesn't use all the opcodes available in the Flash player so, in theory, you can indeed get some performance increase by "manually" writing opcodes.

For example, the Haxe compiler can make use of the Alchemy OpCodes and provide a boost of performance compared to Flash:

> Access Alchemy OpCodes
>
> There are OpCodes for memory allocation hidden in the SWF player which are used by Adobe Alchemy. Haxe has the ability to access them giving you low level memory access which can allow HUGE speed increases.

http://haxe.org/doc/why

I don't know how safe it is to use these opcodes though. Since they are not supported by the official Flash compiler, they might be dropped in a future release of the Flash Player.

Comment: Just a note, Alchemy does not necessarily always equal speed increase. There are situations where it leads to a decrease in performance. There are many blogs by people like Joa Ebert where he basically did pure AS3 vs alchemy code tests and in most of them beat the alchemy version. No matter how great a compiler is, it's no substitute for a professional who can write exceptional code.

Comment: Also a note about your statement on safety of using the op codes, the alchemy op codes you speak of have already been dropped in the latest players including AIR. This is because Adobe is re-writing Alchemy from the ground up.

Comment: @AscensionSystems, the OP was asking if there are things he can do with opcodes that he cannot do with the Flash compiler, and that's the only example I could think of. I wouldn't do it myself but it answers the question anyway.

Comment: So we have alchemy stuff , some optimalization possibilities , is there anything else ?

Comment: @Laurent no, that is not something that the compiler cannot do. The alchemy package contains a modified ASC.jar which can work with those op codes.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to what Laurent posted. ASC is the ActionScript compiler used by Adobe products so far (MXML uses the code from ASC and the compiler in Flash CS has the customized build of it, but neither greatly affects the actual compiler, but act as the front end / "glue" to the linker and other utilities).

ASC is not an optimizing compiler. What it means is that it doesn't do any optimizations usually possible when compiling to lower level language. It analyzes the generated bytecode only to the level to make *mostly* certain it's not erroneous. (It is still possible that the compiler will generate an erroneous code from valid AS3 code).

There isn't one to one correspondence between all valid code you can write in bytecode and AS3. Which means that AS3 limits you to a subset of what is possible in bytecode. It is absolutely possible that in the resulting bytecode you would see how it is easier to get a certain value, when it is on stack, but there will be no tool in AS3 to get it from there. For example, you could've avoided creating a loop iterator relying on that the first register contains the iterator, if you know that the rest of the code inside the loop will never read/write to the first register. Obviously there are a lot more "features" you can discover when you analyze the way bytecode is processed.

But, it is important to understand that locally optimizing you will hardly achieve anything significant unless your goal is fine grained and very specific. Such as, for example, some particular cryptographic algorithm or string parsing routine etc. Optimizing by hand larger pieces of program is *really* difficult. In fact, so difficult that you will need a tool to at least verify yourself that you are actually optimizing. In the end, you will find yourself using this tool to generate the optimized variants of code and test them - and this is how compilers are built :)